# What if a Typer command returns a value

Tags: python, typer

I'm using [Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) to implement a CLI tool. For testing purpose, I'd like some commands return some value, but I'm not sure whether it's safe. I didn't find anything related in its [user guide](https://typer.tiangolo.com/).

As Typer uses [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/), I found the following statements in [Click user guide](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/#:%7E:text=When%20a%20Click%20script%20is%20invoked%20as%20command%20line%20application%20(through%20BaseCommand.main())%20the%20return%20value%20is%20ignored):

> When a Click script is invoked as command line application (through BaseCommand.main()) the return value is ignored unless the standalone_mode is disabled in which case it’s bubbled through.

Does this behavior also apply to Typer?

---

As a minimum example, I'd like to do change my original code

```
@app.command()
def my_command():
    do_something()
```

to

```
@app.command()
def my_command():
    result = do_something()
    return result
```

where `result` is only for testing so that I can test `my_command` with:

```
from typer.testing import CliRunner
from myapp import app

def test_my_command():
    result = CliRunner().invoke(app)
    assert result.return_value == expected_value
```

My question is whether the change (adding `return result`) will influence the behaviour seen by users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this feature added to the newest version of the typer and it's called `Custom Type` which is accessable in the below link:

https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/parameter-types/custom-types/

Comment: Thank you but I'm afraid we are not discussing on the same thing? My case is like `def command(): do_something; return some_value` where `some_value` is used only for testing. I'm wondering if adding `return some_value` will change the behavior of running `app command` in CLI.

Comment: So you mean you want to use echo in typer?

Comment: No. I added an example to the question to clearify.